# Realm how to use `insertOrUpdate` and `copyToRealm` for update and save

Tags: android, realm

I got a list of `users` from server using Retrofit2, I want to save or update them in my local DB using Realm.

This is the code I am using to save or update my list

```
for (User user : users) {
                User user1 = mRealm.where(User.class).equalTo("userId", userId).findFirst();
                if (user1 != null) {
                    mRealm.insertOrUpdate(user); // update
                } else {
                    user.setUserId(userId);
                    mRealm.copyToRealm(user); // save
                }
            }
```

Is it right way I am using this to update? If I am wrong how to use it(save/update) without setting all properties again in Realm.

Comment: There is no difference in the behavior of `insertOrUpdate()` and `copyToRealm()` in this case apart from that `copy` returns a managed proxy (which you don't seem to use) and `insert` doesn't. Generally if your `userId` is annotated with `@PrimaryKey` then `insertOrUpdate()` handles both cases equally.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce Thank you for your quick reply, so if I am using `@Primarykey` for `userId` it will updates the data which is came from server right? There is no need of setting all properties again right? What I am using is correct/

Comment: All fields that you received from the server will be used as the field values that are saved to the db. Null is taken as `null` value.

Comment: Okay. Thank you I'll update once it works..

Comment: @EpicPandaForce As you told in first comment if there is no difference in both then is it updates the existing user or saves as new ?

Comment: `insertOrUpdate` will insert if does not exist by primary key, and update (pretty much overwrite) if it does exist by primary key

Comment: oh okay thanks again for your clarification..